# RuntimeError: OrderedDict mutated during iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, iteration, ordereddictionary

I'm relatively new to python3 & am trying to iterate over a preexisting `OrderedDict()` to remove entries with `None` as the value. In python2 this wasn't a problem, but it's my understanding that the removal of `dict.iteritems()` (etc...) was due to some changes in the way `dict.items()` is returned.

#### I *reeeeeeeeeeally* want to avoid copying the dictionary...

I'm going to be doing (potentially hundreds of) thousands of these & I don't want to double the amount of memory I'm using just to remove null entries from an `OrderedDict`.

#### Here's the code that's throwing the error:

```
class DefaultHeaders(OrderedDict):
    def __init__(self, loop=None):
        super(DefaultHeaders, self).__init__()

        self['User-Agent'] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64; rv:16.0.1) Gecko/20121011 Firefox/16.0.1" # <--(dummy User-Agent header for consistent response-format)
        self['X-Search-ClientIP'] = gethostbyname(gethostname())                                                 
        self['X-MSEdge-ClientID'] = None
        self['Accept'] = None
        self['Accept-Language'] = None
        self['X-Search-Location'] = None

        self._clean1() # <--raises error
        # self._clean2() # <--raises error
        # self._clean3() # <--raises error

    def _clean1(self):
        for k, v in self.items():
            if k in ('count', 'offset'):
                pass
            elif not v: del self[k]

    def _clean2(self):
        for k, v in list(self.items()):
            if k in ('count', 'offset'):
                pass
            elif not v: del self[k]


    def _clean3(self):
        _iter_this = list(self.items())
        for k, v in _iter_this:
            if k in ('count', 'offset'):
                pass
            elif not v: del self[k]
```

And here's the error I'm getting:

```
...
    for k, v in self.items():
RuntimeError: OrderedDict mutated during iteration

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: You're not going to double your memory usage by copying the OrderedDict. That only copies the OrderedDict itself, not its keys or values. Just copy it.

Comment: can you expand on that? Doesn't instantiating a new class-instance come with overhead?

Comment: Also, you only need to keep a copy of one OrderedDict at a time; cleaning 1000 OrderedDicts and copying each one to clean it will only require 1001 OrderedDicts at a time, not 2000.

Comment: "Doesn't instantiating a new class-instance come with overhead?" - yes, but that overhead is much smaller than you seem to think.

Comment: To do the equivalent of what you were doing in Python 2, use `for k, v in list(self.items()): ...`, note, you are making a *new list* out of the items, although, that will be a "shallow copy" of the items (i.e., only the references, not whole new objects).

Comment: Also, `_clean2` and `_clean3` shouldn't have raised an error.

Comment: If you're right than that's true. Can you expand on "cleanning 1000 OrderedDicts and copying each one to clean it will only require 1001.., not 200"?

Comment: oh wait...yeah, `_clean2` & `_clean3` do work. I have a similar class for URL-params that I wasn't changing. (>_<)

Comment: While you clean the dict, you will have a copy. Once you're done cleaning it, the copy can be discarded and its memory reclaimed. As you will only be cleaning one dict at a time, you do not need to keep copies of multiple dicts at a time.

Comment: Ok thanks for this; I'm splitting hairs now, but wouldn't filtering be more slightly more efficient than copying...just because while copying I'm still iterating over the whole thing w/ some criterion-check?

Comment: @RobTruxal yes, marginally so, but it isn't possible to mutate a `dict` while iterating over it. this sounds like something you should worry about only *if* you encounter some memory issue. I.e., this is a premature optimization

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I prematurely optimize all the time! My girlfriend get's mad but I don't care. No but, srsly this is going into an `asyncio` package. The more I can do functionally the better, and the scale this thing supposed to be able to grow to means I gotta pay attention to this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

(>_<) i feel a little dumb but that's not new lol. Thanks to everyone who posted answers. Here's what I've got now:

```
def _clean(self):
    for k in list(self.keys()):
        if k in ('count', 'offset'):
            pass
        elif not self[k]:
            del self[k]
```

Also I realized copying isn't an option. I'd need to reassign `self` & creating a new instance of my class calls `_clean()` producing infinite recursion.

Comment: You forgot to check whether the values are actually None, and the list comprehension is building an unnecessary list.

Comment: yeah. fixed it now.

Comment: The list comprehension is one allocation, the `list()` call is basically creating a copy of the whole dict and `in` is an O(n) lookup. I would say this does not help the case;)

Comment: To use an generator instead: `[ordered_dict.pop(k) for k, v in ordered_dict.items() if k not in ['count', 'offset'] or ordered_dict[k] == None]`

Comment: can't do that Zach. calling `pop(k)` while iterating over `ordered_dict` raises an error

Comment: Ah, you're right Rob. Ah, it only works in python2. Calling list on `ordered_dict.items()` defeats the purpose of using a generator.

Comment: @liborm: The only `in` lookup is in a fixed length-2 tuple, so that's probably fine. The `in` in `for k, v in` is iteration, not a lookup.

Comment: @liborm (you're popular on this thread ;) QQ: SO I'M ACTUALLY RAISING THE MEMORY-NEEDED BY CALLING `list()` & SHOULD JUST COPY LIKE I'M BEING TOLD?

Comment: @RobTruxal well, not just that, but you are using a dictionary comprehension for the side-effect, you are essentially creating a *list of the popped keys* and then discarding it, all for no reason. You'd be better off with the for-loop, `for k,v in list(d.items()): <pop stuff>`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga actually that's a really good point. `pop()` returns a value. Totally forgot about that.

Comment: @RobTruxal well, even if it didn't you would still be populating a totally useless list of `None`s

Comment: agree. changing it.

Comment: @RobTruxal what about not including the `None` keys in the `__init__`? Or another way - you'll be probably printing/dumping the contents of the dict at some point - so you can include the check to skip empty ones there. Two problems solved in single iteration over the dict.

Comment: I agree completely; that will allow me to keep the cleaning procedure I/O-centric. Can you provide an answer that says this^, so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

What about iterating the dictionary with an index?:

```
    def _clean4(self):
        i = 0

        while i < len(self):
            if self.keys()[i] not in ('count', 'offset') and not self[self.keys()[i]]:
                del self[self.keys()[i]]
            else:
                i = i + 1
```

Comment: You can't index `self.keys()` on Python 3, and on Python 2, back when you could index `self.keys()`, it was because the function created an entire list every time you called it.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this:

```
[ordered_dict.pop(k) for k in ordered_dict if k not in ['count', 'offset'] or ordered_dict[k] == None]
```

Comment: This is even wronger. It's still mutating the dict while iterating over it, but now it's not even checking the values.

Comment: So you are saying that the comprehension won't operate on all of the keys? I disagree, as [k for k in ordered_dict] creates a list before it starts iteration. This way, each key is checked regardless of whether it has been 'popped'. Dict is a hash so there can't be dup keys. Each key is evaluated, maybe popped, then the iteration proceeds regardless of what happened.

Comment: high-five to @user2357112 for using the word "wronger." Big fan.